# Trouble calling a superclass method from inside a subclass static method

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I have a class `Mouse` that extends the class `Mammal`. In `Mouse`, I have a static method which takes in as parameter an `ArrayList` of `Mouse` objects, like this:

```
public static void mate(ArrayList<Mouse> mice)
```

Inside this static method, I have this line of code:

```
if((mice.get(i).getIsMale ^ mice.get(j).getIsMale) && (mice.get(i).getAge > 1 ) &&  (mice.get(j).getAge > 1 ) )
    //if either mouse is male but not both and if both are older than 1 day
```

where `getIsMale` and `getAge` are methods defined in the superclass Mammal, and `i` and `j` are variables I use inside the static `mate` method.

I get 4 errors from the compiler in the above line: Cannot find symbol. One for each `getIsMale` and one for each `getAge`

I would appreciate any (quick) help. I have to submit this assignment and go to sleep. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer (:-P): You have to add brackets so that it's `getIsMale()` and `getAge()`. All functions must be called with brackets, in Java.

Style comment: Boolean getters should normally be named `isXXX`, not `getXXX`, so your `male` getter should be named `isMale`, not `getIsMale`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your code:

```
if ((mice.get(i).getIsMale ^ mice.get(j).getIsMale) && 
    (mice.get(i).getAge > 1 ) && 
    (mice.get(j).getAge > 1 )) {
    // ...
}
```

The way that this is written, you are saying "give me the value of the field `getIsMale`" and so on.  It `getAge` and `getIsMale` are not fields: they are methods.  So you have to *call* them:

```
if ((mice.get(i).getIsMale() ^ mice.get(j).getIsMale()) && 
    (mice.get(i).getAge() > 1 ) && 
    (mice.get(j).getAge() > 1 )) {
    // ...
}
```

(The reason that the Java compiler says "symbol not found" rather than "its a field" is that field names and method names are in different name spaces.  If you wanted to, you could write a class that has both a field called `foo` and a method called `foo`.  So ... the compiler is telling you about the error that it sees, rather than trying to guess what you might have actually meant.)

---

Minor point: The JavaBeans convention says that a getter for a boolean property should be called `isXxx` rather than `getXxx`.  You should rename `getIsMale()` to be `isMale()`.

Comment: +1 for also bringing up the boolean getter naming convention. ;-) (Actually I upvoted you even sooner than that, but that happens to be a peeve of mine, so it's nice when others reinforce that. :-))

Comment: God, I kept scratching my head for so long trying to find out what was wrong, and the brackets didn't occur to me at all. Thanks for the replies!